# multiple harddrives instalation

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, dropbox

can anybody help me with setting up harddrives during install ubuntu?

I have 3 hardrives (1SSD and two HDD)

But after i installed ubuntu on SSD, that two HDDs are located here:

/media/jakub/84bc0b5c-1072-4722-97ce-a6255d3b6eca

What is this? Is there any way how to make them easier to find?

I dont know, if this is due wrong setup of harddrives, but i have dropbox installed and i setup location of files on second HDD. but after restart dropbox couldnt find that location so it moved it back into /home directory.

Comment: First about your 2 drives. They are auto-mounted in the /media/<user name> directory with a generated mount point by the name of the UUID of the disk. Of course you can make them easier to find. Create 2 new directories in /media/jakub. Run `sudo fdisk -l` and you will see the partition(s) of your disks; f.e. /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1. Using the `disks` utility you can add the partitions to `/etc/fstab` and mount them to the 2 directories you just created.

Comment: About dropbox. By default Dropbox creates a /home/<user>/dropbox directory. Only when Dropbox has installed ans configured itself,  you Pause Synchronization and move the Dropbox directory to another location.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments. Your questions are not due to an error in Ubuntu/Dropbox. Both topics you mentioned are just default behavior and you can use my tips to tune your system to your liking.